# Android fails to send unicast UDP

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp

I have the following setup:
My computer is a hotspot via a WiFi adapter, with a server application running on it (code irrelevant and ugly but I can post if it matters). My computer's IP address is 192.168.66.1.

I wrote an android app that sends a UDP packet to it, and the packet ONLY appears on wireshark if I send it to 255.255.255.255. If I try to change the destination to 192.168.66.255, or 192.168.66.1, it simply doesn't appear on wireshark and no error is reported on the device. (I also change the socket to broadcast(false) when trying unicast)

This is the sending code that doesn't work:

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {         

    public ClientThread()
    {
        super();                        
    }           

    private void sendCmd(DatagramSocket s, ByteArrayOutputStream cmd) throws Exception
    {
        InetAddress inet;
        inet = getBroadcastAddress(getApplicationContext());
        Log.d("ScreenToggler", inet.toString());
        //DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(cmd.toByteArray(), cmd.toByteArray().length, InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"), ScreenToggler.SERVERPORT);
        //s.setBroadcast(true);
        DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(cmd.toByteArray(), cmd.toByteArray().length, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.66.1"), ScreenToggler.SERVERPORT);
        s.setBroadcast(false);
        s.send(dataPacket);
        Log.d("ScreenToggler", "Sent packet");
    }

    public void run() {                     
        DatagramSocket socket = null;


        try
        {
            try
            {                   
                socket = new DatagramSocket(ScreenToggler.SERVERPORT);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("ScreenToggler", "S: Error", e);
                return;
            }

            Log.d("ScreenToggler", "C: Connecting...");

            System.out.println(CmdToSend.toByteArray().length);
            sendCmd(socket, CmdToSend);

            socket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("ScreenToggler", "S: Error", e);
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e2)
            {}
        }                                           
    }
}
```

When I try to send with this code, no exceptions occur, flow continues normally, and nothing appears on wireshark. No indications that something ever went wrong - such as my android's refusal to send out packets.

If I uncomment the two lines

```
//DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(cmd.toByteArray(), cmd.toByteArray().length, InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"), ScreenToggler.SERVERPORT);
//s.setBroadcast(true);
```

and re-comment their two corresponding lines, the packet appears on wireshark and is received properly on the server application on my computer. My computer's firewall is off.

Here's my manifest file for the permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="zomg.screenshutter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="zomg.screenshutter.ScreenToggler"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Other possibly relevant info I have is my android's IP address is 192.168.66.101, and it recognizes 192.168.66.1 as its gateway (when I try to get the gateway address via the wifi manager it indeed returns my computer's address).

I have no idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: What is about your network mask? I think it should be 255.255.255.0. If so then the broadcast address is 192.168.66.255

Comment: Which doesn't do anything either (when setting the socket to either broadcast or unicast). Only 255.255.255.255 works =\
edit: My netmask is indeed 255.255.255.0 by the way, forgot to confirm

Answer (score 0):

I've built a socket class a little time ago. I've tested it

If you're send a broadcast you need to know your braodcast address which is built on your ip-address (192.168.178.14) and your new-mask (255.255.255.0). Simply type "ifconfig" to your shell and see the ip after "Bcast". You need a port number too, for me it's always 9999 (choose one abouve 1024, because every number below is reserved for other services)

```
public class SocketService {
    private Handler mHandler;

    // threads
    private UDPReceiveThread mUDPReceiveThread;

    // UDP
    private DatagramSocket mUDPSendSocket;
    private DatagramPacket mUDPPacket;
    private byte[] mUDPSendData;

    public SocketService(Handler handler) {
            mHandler = handler;
            try {
                    mUDPReceiveThread = new UDPReceiveThread(9999);
                    mUDPReceiveThread.start();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                    mUDPSendSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void close() {
            try {
                    mUDPSendSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void writeUDP(String message, String address, int port) {
            if (null == mUDPSendData)
                    mUDPSendData = new byte[1024];

            if (null != mUDPSendSocket) {
                    InetAddress ipAddress;
                    try {
                            ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
                            mUDPSendData = message.getBytes();
                            mUDPPacket = new DatagramPacket(mUDPSendData, mUDPSendData.length, ipAddress, port);
                            new UDPSendThread().start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
    }

    private class UDPSendThread extends Thread {
            public void run() {
                    try {
                            mUDPSendSocket.send(mUDPPacket);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
    }

    private class UDPReceiveThread extends Thread {
            private DatagramSocket tReceiveSocket;
            DatagramPacket tReceivePacket;
            private byte[] tReceiveData;
            private String tMessage = null;

            public UDPReceiveThread(int port) throws SocketException {
                    tReceiveSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
                    tReceiveData = new byte[1024];
                    tReceivePacket = new DatagramPacket(tReceiveData, tReceiveData.length);
            }

            public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                            try {
                                    tReceiveSocket.receive(tReceivePacket);
                                    tMessage = new String(tReceivePacket.getData(), "UTF-8").substring(0, tReceivePacket.getLength());
                                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_NEW_UDP_DATA, tReceivePacket.getLength(), -1, tMessage).sendToTarget();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

            }
    }
```

}

and here is my MainActivity which uses the class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private SocketService mService;

    private String mUdpSendIp = "192.168.178.255";

    //views
    private Button bUdpSend;

    //messages
    public static final int MESSAGE_NEW_UDP_DATA = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_NEW_TCP_DATA = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mService = new SocketService(mHandler);

            //find views
            TextView tvUdpTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_udpTitle);
            bUdpSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_udpSend);

            //configure views
            tvUdpTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textBlue));
            bUdpSend.setOnClickListener(new buttonListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }

    public class buttonListener implements OnClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(v.equals(bUdpSend)) {
                            EditText etUdpMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_udpMessage);
                            mService.writeUDP(etUdpMessage.getText().toString(), mUdpSendIp, 9999);
                    }
            }
    }

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    switch(msg.what) {
                    case MESSAGE_NEW_UDP_DATA:
                            String message = (String) msg.obj;
                            TableLayout tl_udpReceive = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl_udpReceive);

                            TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                            TextView tvNewMessage = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                            tvNewMessage.setText(message);
                            tvNewMessage.setTextSize(16);
                            tvNewMessage.setTextColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.textBlue));
                            tr.addView(tvNewMessage);
                            tl_udpReceive.addView(tr);
                            final ScrollView tmp = (ScrollView)tl_udpReceive.getParent();
                            tmp.post(new Runnable() {            
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    tmp.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);              
                                }
                            });

                            break;
                    }
            }
    };
```

}

Comment: I prefer to send it directly to the unicast IP address. I expect to see maybe an ARP request/reply pair and then my message being sent but nothing happens at all. Also as mentioned sending to the subnet broadcast address doesn't work either for me - I can't notice any meaningful difference between your code and mine, either.